# Method not found when emitting a custom signal, but the game seems to work when played

Tags: godot, gdscript

In Godot 4.1.1 I moved some scenes and started getting parenting errors. I think I got that fixed, but I'm mentioning it in case it is important.

I have an Area2d called House.
house.gd has two custom signals

```
signal player_entered
signal player_exited

func _on_body_entered(body):
    print("Emitting player_entered")
    player_entered.emit()

func _on_body_exited(body):
    print("Emitting player_exited")
    player_exited.emit()
```

The custom signals are connected to a scene called Outside.

In outside.gd I have

```
func _on_house_player_entered():
    print("Player Entered House!")
    var tween = get_tree().create_tween()
    tween.tween_property($Player/Camera2D,"zoom",Vector2(.5,.5),1)

func _on_house_player_exited():
    print("Player Exited House!")
    var tween = get_tree().create_tween()
    tween.tween_property($Player/Camera2D,"zoom",Vector2(.2,.2),1)
```

When I run the outside scene, I can enter the house and the camera zooms. I can exit the house and the camera zoom resets.

So far, so good.

The debugger gives two errors:

> E 0:00:35:0663   house.gd:20 @ _on_body_entered(): Error calling from
> signal 'player_entered' to callable:
> 'Area2D(house.gd)::_on_player_entered': Method not found.   <C++
> Source>   core/object/object.cpp:1082 @ emit_signalp()   
> house.gd:20 @ _on_body_entered()

and

> E 0:00:36:0414   house.gd:26 @ _on_body_exited(): Error calling from
> signal 'player_exited' to callable:
> 'Area2D(house.gd)::_on_player_exited': Method not found.   <C++
> Source>   core/object/object.cpp:1082 @ emit_signalp()   
> house.gd:26 @ _on_body_exited()

I removed the relevant code from both files, re-attached all four signals and pasted the code back in the files. I still get the errors. What am I doing wrong? (I'm only 7 hours into my first lesson, so there's a lot I don't know.)

Comment: The errors are telling you that it is trying to call methods `_on_player_entered` and `_on_player_exited` which were connected to the signals, but it cannot find them. You must have removed then or renamed them without updating the signal connection.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the signals did exist. I can only assume it was some sort of path issue caused by me moving the scene.

Comment: I didn't say the say the *signals* (`player_entered`, `player_exited`) didn't exist, I said the *methods* (`_on_player_entered`, `_on_player_exited`) weren't found.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to carefully disconnect every signal from every node involved, then re-implement and reconnect each signal. Now it works with no error. Because I don't know what goes on in the background, I don't know what the root cause was. I'd be happy to accept someone else's answer if they can explain it.